# Does a high value for covariance suggest a strong relationship?

Tags: covariance

I have a data set consisting of about 100,000 rows and two columns. The values in one column range from 0 to 10^9 the values in the other column range from 0 to 245. I've calculated the covariance between these two values and the result is 5x10^8. I realise this suggests two things:

```
1) There is a correlation
2) It's a positive correlation
```

However, I'm now trying to read into this a little further. Does the magnitude of the value have any significance? Would a higher or lower (but still >0) value suggest a closer correlation or can the covariance not be used for this type of analysis? If it can't can anything other than linear regression?

Comment: There is a positive correlation but it is not possible to find its strength since the value of covariance depends on the size of your data. Compute instead the Pearson correlation coefficient which is the covariance statistic normalized to be between -1 and +1.

Comment: @Epaminondas do you mean the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient?

Comment: With so much data, correlation is a crude tool to characterize or understand the relationship between the variables.  Start with investigating what their scatterplot looks like.

Comment: To add to @whuber 's comment, I would plot a sample of the 100,000 points as a scatter plot with 100,000 points will be a mass of black ink. I'd also look at loess lines (or some other smoother) on the full data set.

Comment: One could plot tiny points (possibly with some jitter), or use transparency to deal with the "mass of black ink" issue.